# Толстовка и Лев Толстой

Tags: этимология

Сейчас толстовками называют пайты с капюшоном. Раньше, насколько я понимаю, нечто вроде русской рубахи. Но какой отношение эта самая пайта имеет к Зеркалу Русской Революции? Почему она - толстовка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Толстой в конце своей жизни был кумиром и образцом для подражания. Именно, благодаря ему получил распространение такой вид одежды как толстовка. Наряд в России того времени имел важное значение для классовой дифференциации. Мужик от барина по одежке отличались очень и очень сильно. Толстовка должна была помочь писателю эту разницу уменьшить, но в то же время не выглядеть ряженным. В отличии от косоворотки вырез толстовки был в центре, но в целом от крестьянской рубахи отличалась она мало. Благодаря популярности Толстого во всём мире, одежда получила широкое распространение. Она оказалась удобной, и хоть и с изменениями, но пережила своего создателя уже на добрую сотню лет.

Лев Толстой в толстовке:

[image]

Comment: Это не толстовка. Вопреки Марку Изу. Вы бы хоть в терминах разобрались. Это именно рубаха, видимо - холщовая.

Comment: @behemothus, почему косоворотка так называется? Потому, что ворот застёгивается сбоку, а не по центру. По версии Лихачёва, этот дизайн появился для того, чтобы крестик не выпадал при работе. На снимке же чётко видно, что вырез горловины рубахи Толстого расположен ровно по центру. Так что в терминах в данном случае, следует разобраться вам

Answer (score 1):

Вынужден внести уточнение по сути.

Я таки думаю, что всё ж не "благодаря ему", а благодаря толстовцам, кои рядились в эти одежды. Носил ли сам граф нечто подобное - неизвестно. Зато хорошо известно, что под конец жизни (после очередного переворота в мировоззернии) он предпочитал рубаху-косоворотку или летнюю куртку-холщёвку без воротника. Возможно название холщёвка в какой-то мере сказалась и на образовании слова "толстовка".
А вообще - см. тут http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Толстой, вопреки Википедии толстовку носил. Посмотрите хотя бы его фотографии, или портреты. Естественно, сам писатель, подобную рубаху толстовкой не называл, но если б не носил он, то и толстовцы подобный тип одежды, не надевали бы. Поэтому вид одежды "получил распространение, благодаря ему", а само название дали уже другие. Писать то, что Толстой не мог называть свою рубаху, рубаха как у Толстого я посчитал излишним.

Да, толстовка в то время - это рубаха с воротом по центру, без капюшона.